# Key handling routines

Tags: windows

Is there anyway to modify the key handling routine that the Windows Login Screen uses to allow a barcode with the username, 2key tab character ($I), and a password to log in a user. I cannot get the login screen to recognize the TAB character to tab to the password text field. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [write your own gina.dll](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742447.aspx), and create your own login dialog. By replacing the login dialog you can take care of the input in whatever way you want. I've never done this and it doesn't seem to be a straightforward chore, but you might be able to find some example code on the Web.

Comment: If you're trying to modify the Windows Login Screen, I'm pretty sure a custom GINA is the only way to do this. Be careful with installing it and preserving the GINA chains on install and uninstall.

Comment: GINAs were phased out four years prior to that answer, with Windows NT 6.0, and replaced by credential providers.